# Get data from Select top

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

I already had a question answered on my previous problem [Select top using SQL Server returns different output than select *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212106/select-top-using-sql-server-returns-different-output-than-select)

I want to get `select top n` data from a database based on alphabetical & numbering format. The output must order by alphabet first and number after that.

When I try to get all data (`select *`), I get the correct output:

```
select nocust, share 
from TB_STOCK
where share = ’BBCA’ 
  and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZZZZZ’
order by 
    case when nocust like ‘[a-z]%’ then 0 else 1 end, nocust


nocust | share
-------+--------
a522   | BBCA
b454   | BBCA
k007   | BBCA
p430   | BBCA
q797   | BBCA
s441   | BBCA
s892   | BBCA
u648   | BBCA
v107   | BBCA
4211   | BBCA
6469   | BBCA
6751   | BBCA
```

when I try to `select top n` (ex : top 5), I got the right data too :

```
select top 5 nocust, share 
from TB_STOCK
where share = ’BBCA’ 
  and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZZZZZ’
order by 
    case when nocust like ‘[a-z]%’ then 0 else 1 end, nocust

nocust | share
-------+--------
a522   | BBCA
b454   | BBCA
k007   | BBCA
p430   | BBCA
q797   | BBCA
```

**The problem is when i try to get next top 5 based on last nocust & share on previous top 5 data**
   `(concat(share, nocust) < 'ZZZZq797'))` 
it return wrong expected data :

```
select top 5 nocust, share 
from TB_STOCK
where share = ’BBCA’ 
and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZq797’
order by 
case when nocust like ‘[a-z]%’ then 0 else 1 end, nocust

nocust | share
-------+--------
a522   | BBCA
b454   | BBCA
k007   | BBCA
p430   | BBCA
q797   | BBCA
```

it should return :

```
nocust | share
-------+--------
s441   | BBCA
s892   | BBCA
u648   | BBCA
v107   | BBCA
4211   | BBCA
```

I expect the mistake is somewhere between the concat and order by, can someone tell me how to get the right top 5.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a built-in function to get row ranges, but you can always use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
select nocust, share
FROM (
  select nocust, share, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      ORDER BY case when nocust like ‘[a-z]%’ then 0 else 1 end, nocust
    ) AS RowNum -- Assign rows "row numbers" based on `ORDER BY`
  from TB_STOCK
  where share = ’BBCA’ 
    and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZZZZZ’
) src
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN <start_row_num> AND <end_row_num> -- Get specified row range
order by 
  case when nocust like ‘[a-z]%’ then 0 else 1 end, nocust -- Not sure if this is needed
```

This will assign "row numbers" to each row based on your `ORDER BY` and then return only the range of rows you specify in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should show complete query.

Also in your query this thing is not clear to me `and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZZZZZ’`.
I am not getting what type of data you have and what it will return or **what is your expected output**.

I think I will create `Indexed view` in such scenario.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vStockView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    select  nocust, [share] ,
 0  SortCol
from TB_STOCK
where 
--  share = ’BBCA’ 
--  and concat(share, nocust) < ‘ZZZZZZZZ’ 
 -- and 
  isnumeric(nocust)=0

  union all

  select  nocust, [share] ,
 1  SortCol
from TB_STOCK
where 
  isnumeric(nocust)=1

GO
```

Notice what I have commented where condition because that is not require in view.It can be implemented in Proc.

I do not have complete info about your query,table .

So below Index may not be as good.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CX_vStockView
  ON dbo.vStockView(SortCol); 
GO
```

Now you create new proc like this,

```
Create Proc spGETStock
@share varchar(30)
@PageNumber int,
@RowspPage int=30
as

BEGIN
set nocount on

select nocust,[share] 
--,count(*)over() as TotalRecords
from vStockView
where share = @share
ORDER BY SortCol
OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowspPage ROWS ONLY;

End
```

Or you can implement Paging using `Row_Number` in `Sql server 2008` and below.

I am sure it will improve performance significantly.